# Keep timer alive, Ionic 2 Observable.timer after back button pressed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a timer on my page `Observable.timer` when it ends it triggers a `nav.push` to another page. However, when I click the back button inside the app or hardware back button the `Observable.timer` triggers the `nav.push`. How can I keep the timer counting down even when going back in the nav stack?

```
  countDown: any;
  counter = 1*10;
  tick = 1000;
  status:any;

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,  public storage: Storage,  public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
      this.startTimer();
  }
          startTimer() {
            this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
              .take(this.counter)
              .map(() => --this.counter).finally(() => this.endTimer());
              //this.countDown.subscribe(() => { }); 
          }
```

Comment: Just move your timer to provider and pass timer value to your pages.

Comment: Any example code would be useful..

Comment: Moving the timer to a provider results in the same problem, cant click back without ending the timer